# Unable to store Date in a specific format in database

Tags: java, date, datetime, timestamp

reading json data from database, and converting it into a object in java.

```
Data in Database :- {"id":123,"expiryDate":"2024-02-10"}
```

NOTE :- I am trying to use this data in **Google Web Toolkit (GWT)**

converting above data using object mapper.
Object consuming above json TestJson.java

```
 Class TestJson {
 private Long id,
 private Date expiryDate;
 public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id= id;
}

public Date getExpiryDate() {
    return expiryDate;
}

public void setExpiryDate(Date expiryDate) {
    this.expiryDate = expiryDate;
}
public String toJSONString() {
     return "{" +
                "\"id\" : \"" + id + "\"," +
                "\"expiryDate\" : \"" + expiryDate + "\"}";
}
}
```

When the Json data is converted then the value of "Expiry Date" is "Sat Feb 10 05:30:00 IST 2024".
But I want it in the same format as it is in JSON.

Comment: Have a look at the Javadocs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString-- and you will see that it is doing exactly what it says it will do.  Try searching for ways to format a Java Date.

Comment: As has been said many many times on Stack Overflow, both `Date` classes are terribly flawed, and are now legacy. They were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. For a date-only value, use `LocalDate` class.

Comment: Your input string complies with ISO 8601 standard used by default when parsing/generating strings in *java.time*. So simply parse: `LocalDate.parse( "2024-02-10" )`. To generate such a string: `myLocalDate.toString()`.

Comment: Tip: In the Java ecosystem, you have your choice of many good JSON processing frameworks. I suggest you use one. See: [*JSON in Java*](https://www.baeldung.com/java-json) by Eugen Paraschiv on Baeldung.com.

Comment: Use `LocalDate` and use for example [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8) and get exactly that format, which is also recommended. What you are seeing is the result of the `toString` method of the outdated `java.util.Date` class; you neither want that class nor that format.

Comment: You're expecting the `Date` object to remember that it should be printed in a specific format, but it doesn't work like that. A `Date` object does not have a format by itself; it's just a date and time value. To print it in a specific format, you'd have to use a `SimpleDateFormat` object.

Answer (score 1):

Since I was trying to save/parse the object in Google Web Toolkit (GWT) so SimpleDateFormat was creating issue, as GWT doesn't supports SimpleDateFormat.

But below worked for me

```
import com.google.gwt.i18n.shared.DateTimeFormat;
import com.google.gwt.i18n.shared.DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo;
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd"; /*your pattern here*/ 
DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo info = new DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo();
DateTimeFormat df = new DateTimeFormat(pattern, info) {};
df.format(expiryDate)
```

Output :-

```
{"id":123,"expiryDate" : "2024-02-10"}
```